# "Occlusion culling data is out of date. Please rebake" - No scene specified, Unity 5.6.2

Tags: unity

I've inherited a Unity project with hundreds of scenes. When I try to build it for consoles/mobile I get 11 errors saying "Occlusion culling data is out of date. Please rebake" and the build fails. Double clicking on these errors takes me nowhere, and no scenes are specified. It is my understanding that I can only bake occlusion culling by opening the scene manually and hitting the bake button. Due to the size of this project, that would take many hours. The game runs fine from within the editor, but simply won't export to consoles.

How can I do any of the following:

1. Automatically rebuild all occlusion culling information.
2. Find which scenes are out of date.
3. Disable occlusion culling project wide, letting me at least get a build onto dev-kits out for further evaluation.

Thanks for any help at all.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is from August 2017, but I just had a similar issue in Unity 2018.2 and this has not been answered. I opened an old project that I had been working on in Unity 5 and one particular scene had the error. To resolve, I did the following:

Click Window > Rendering > Occlusion Culling

This brought up the Occlusion Culling settings.
There is a button at the bottom that is labelled "BAKE". I clicked on this.
I then saved the scene and the project, then Quit and Relaunched Unity and it worked

Here is the link to the Unity article on Occlusion Culling:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html